# Listbox "does not exist in the current context" error in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I was trying out Mahapp Metro ( using VS 2012 Express), so i tried to write a sample application, so I just created a window, threw in a listbox, and a button. The button is supposed to add a new list item to the listbox on button click.

Since this is just a test app, I just wanted to use a simple code behind procedure. But when i reference my listbox named " listboxTest " in the code behind,I get the error " the name " listboxTest " does not exist in the current context ". But this is just a direct reference to the listbox in the code behind. I checked if I made a mistake with the case since C# is case sensitive, but I did not. I added all the namespaces (some unnecessary ones as well) but in vain. the code is below

xaml:

```
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Eloq_Home.TestWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:Behaviours="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Behaviours;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:Eloq_Home.Views"
    Title="TestWindow" Height="402" Width="497">

<Grid>

    <ListBox x:Name="listboxTest" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource KeysListBox}" 
                                  Height="278" Margin="91,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="319">

        <ListBoxItem />
        <ListBoxItem />
        <ListBoxItem />
        <ListBoxItem />            

    </ListBox>

    <Button x:Name="addTest" Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                             Height="45" Margin="263,317,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119" Click="addTest_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using MahApps.Metro.Controls;
using MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;

namespace Eloq_Home
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for TestWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
public partial class TestWindow : MetroWindow
{
    public TestWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void addTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxItem itm = new ListBoxItem();
        //itm.Content = "some text";

        listboxTest.Items.Add(itm);
    }         

}
```

}

Error:

" listboxTest.Items.Add(itm);" this is the line where I have that error, and well I get the same error whenever I try to reference the listbox, I tried to set it's item source, got the same error.

I absolutely know this is a rookie question but I am stuck, any help is appreciated.

[image]

IT works where I comment out that single line where I reference my listbox

Comment: I checked the possibility of that. I just commented out the line where I have the error and ran the application, it works. I will post a screenshot of the app working.

Comment: I knew there was something funny about this. I opened the same project in VS 2010 Ultimate and it works perfectly. But it does not work in VS 2012 Express. I am not an expert on VS and the various .NET frameworks, so I would like to know what happened here, if anybody knows.

Comment: I tested it on VS 2012 Ultimate edition and confirm that there are no errors. I have just ignored the `Style` of the `ListBox` from your code.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove **Style="{StaticResource KeysListBox}"** from ListBox tag..it will work :-)

Comment: I did so, the error still persists, that's why I am perplexed.

Comment: please make the line itm.Content = "some text"; uncomment

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it works fine `VS2012` `Ultimate` edition. Can you please test again?

Below is the code

```
<metro:MetroWindow x:Class="TestListBox.TestWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:metro="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="325" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox x:Name="listboxTest" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                              Height="100" Margin="91,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="319">
            <ListBoxItem />
            <ListBoxItem />
            <ListBoxItem />
            <ListBoxItem />
        </ListBox>

        <Button x:Name="addTest" Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="45" Margin="91,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119" Click="addTest_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</metro:MetroWindow>
```

I have not changed your code behind at all. I have just uncommented the two lines which you have commented in the `addTest_Click` method.

Comment: Thank you asks81 for taking the time to test it, but unfortunately I dont have VS 2012 Ultimate, I only have the free Express edition and it does not work in VS 2012 Express, it may be a mistake on my part, but I cant see where I could go wrong, because this test app is extremely simple and basic. VS 2012 Ultimate?? that is my question here. The same worked for me in VS 2010 Ultimate though, but not in VS 2012 Express, is there any reason why?

Comment: I will try in VS2012 Express and re-check if I can reproduce the same error. Give me some time.